# Is there a $C^{\infty}$ function $f$ such that the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!} (x-x_0)^n$ is $0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

Is there a $C^{\infty}$ function $f$ such that the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!} (x-x_0)^n$ is $0$?

By the way, I know the following fact:

If $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ for $x \in (-R, R)$ for a positive real number $R$, then $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} x^n$ 
 for $x \in (-R, R)$.

So, if there is a $C^{\infty}$ function $f$ such that the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} x^n$ is $0$, then we cannot write $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ for $x \in (-R, R)$ for a positive real number $R$.

Comment: [Here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function#A_smooth_function_which_is_nowhere_real_analytic).

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Thank you very much for the example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Given *any* sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb Z^+}$ of real numbers, there is a $C^\infty$ function $f$ such that it's Taylor series centered at $0$ is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$. So, take, say, $a_n=n!$ and you're done.

The statement that I mentioned is known as Borel's theorem on power series and you will find a proof at, say, Ádám Besenyei's article [*Peano's unnoticed proof of Borel's theorem*](http://www.cs.elte.hu/~badam/publications/borel.pdf).

Comment: Thank you very much, Jose Carlos Santos.

Answer (score 1):

Choose any sequence a_n such that 
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } a_n  = 0
$$
According to Du-Boys Reymond the function

$$
f(x) = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\left( { - 1} \right)^{n + 1} } \frac{{x^{2n} }}
{{\left[ {\left( {2n} \right)!\left( {x^2  + a^2 _n } \right)} \right]}}
$$

is 
$$
C^\infty  
$$
but its Taylor series in x=0 has convergence radius r=0.

Comment: Thank you very much, Luca.

Comment: You are welcome!